# building gradle in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm new to working with gradle but I'm somewhat familiar with Eclipse. When I discovered I couldn't build gradle projects directly from eclipse, I searched for solutions and chose to create use the external tools Configuration to run my program. I used the "--gui" option in my configurations. 
This worked for a while but lately I've been getting these messages:
Failed to connect to gradle process for command "tasks"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.

> Could not connect to GUI server at port 53503

The port number is different with each error. I've tried restarting eclipse, sometimes that works, most times It doesn't. Does anyone understand this error and know a solution for it

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using? As Eclipse Mars v4.5.1 comes default with Gradle installed.

Comment: I'm currently using Juno. I was using Luna, but I would get null point exceptions whenever I load eclipse, even before I open a project. I downgraded because I have Juno on a different system and I never had that error but when I started getting the GUI port problem for gradle, I knew I needed to try something else. I'm currently trying your suggestion of Mars, Ill update how that goes

Comment: You can use multiple Eclipse version next to each other. Just unzip it, renma ethe eclipse directory, to something like `eclipse-4.5-java`. And start the eclipse inside the directory. On Windows, you can create a short cut, based on the `eclipse.exe`, which can then be copied to the _Start Menu_.

Comment: __Tip:__ Create for each Eclipse version, a new workspaces directory, in which you create workspaces, for that version. Like `$HOME/eclipse-4.5-ws/sample-ws`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your Eclipse version does not come with Gradle installed, search the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/gradle) for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Eclipse Mars v4.5.1, as per the suggestion above, and downloaded the Gradle official plugin for Eclipse, [Buildship](https://gradle.org/press-release/eclipse-gradle/), from the Eclipse Market place

> Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace... -> Search -> Buildship -> Install

Not a solution to my exact question, but a solution to my problem